# Top menu links problem - Magento Community

Tags: navigation, menu

My site is http://envybeautydirect.com/ (still under construction)

The problem: if you click link to any category from top menu, after redirection, this link appears still as hovering over. Click, for instance: Nails or Jewellery

And it happens only to real categorries, If link from top nav follows to a page, it stays normal after redirection. Click, for example: About Us or Delivery

It happened suddenly this morning, before everything was warking fine. I didn't touch the top menu, while it happened.

Any ideas what is it and how to fix it?

Comment: This is CSS 101. It's not really about Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `css/fish_menu.css` there is this around line 26.

```
#nav li.active a,
#nav li.over a,
#nav a:hover { color:#1b0015; background:#b03188; }
```

Remove the first line and make it look like this

```
#nav li.over a,
#nav a:hover { color:#1b0015; background:#b03188; }
```